# Return focus to chrome extension after closing popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing small extension for chrome. In JS for main extension popup I creating second popup. So I have to popups:

1. small with main extension popup.
2. popup with loaded html page.

According to normal situation, when extension lost focus, it's closed. But I have the same situation when I close second popup. Focus return not to first extension popup, but to opened tab.

Is it possible to return focus to first popup when second closing to prevent extension stop?

Extension manifest:

```
// ...
 "action": {
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "background":{}
```

Code for creating popup:

```
chrome.windows.create({
        focused: true,
        height: h,
        incognito: false,
        type: "popup",
        url: url,
        width: w,
        left: left,
        top: top
    }, function (newWindow) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript(
            {
              target: {tabId: newWindow.tabs[0].id},
              func: () => {
                // ...
              }
            });
        chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
            target: {tabId: newWindow.tabs[0].id},
            files: ["inject.css"]
        });
    });
```

I tried to get main popup window id to return focus on close event, but it's default -2.

Comment: If "the first popup" means the built-in `action` popup then there's no way to focus it.